# Overwrite/Don't overwrite option for Dropbox API Upload

Tags: python, api, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have found the following script from an old StackOverflow question which gives an example of how to connect to my Dropbox via the API:

```
import dropbox

client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(<auth_token>)
print 'linked account: ', client.account_info()

f = open('working-draft.txt', 'rb')
response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', f)
print 'uploaded: ', response

folder_metadata = client.metadata('/')
print 'metadata: ', folder_metadata

f, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata('/magnum-opus.txt')
out = open('magnum-opus.txt', 'wb')
out.write(f.read())
out.close()
print metadata
```

I've played around with this and got it to upload the files I want to the Dropbox sub folders I want. However, I am unsure how to specify whether to overwrite a file already present on Dropbox with the same name or not. There do not appear to be any example scripts written that cover this online already.

The API documentation makes reference to an overwrite option as part of chunked uploading [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs/python#ChunkedUploader), but I am unsure how I would work this into the example script shown above.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `put_file` is here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs/python#DropboxClient.put_file.

Just pass `overwrite=True` to overwrite. (The default is `False`.)